# i want to display individual view for a product using slug, but i cannot encounter the positional argument error?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I want to display my each product objects into templates using slug, but i am facing an positional argument error.
Please help me get with it as I am new to django

here is my url path

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.blink_network),  # redirect to root - path
    path('blink_network/', views.blink_network, name='blink_network'),
    path('AddNewProduct/', views.AddNewProduct, name='AddNewProduct'),
    path('blink_viewproduct/', views.showproduct),
    path('blink_viewproduct/', views.blink_viewproduct, name='blink_viewproduct'),
    path('blink_updateproduct/', views.blink_updateproduct, name='blink_updateproduct'),
    path('link/', views.link_view, name='link'),
    path('link_view/<int:uid>', views.link_view, name='link_view'),
]+static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

here is the view

```
#Display individual product
def link_view(request, id):
    results = AffProduct.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request, 'product_view.html', {"results":results})
```

Following is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

Exception Type: TypeError at /affiliation/link/
Exception Value: link_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'id'
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add full traceback for the error.

Comment: i have added the full traceback

Comment: @YeshBiswakarma You get the error at the url `/affiliation/link/`, please show that urlpattern and it's view.

Comment: I have added all the URL patterns, and this is the views only.

Comment: @YeshBiswakarma your view `link_view` expects that an `id` will be passed to it, yet here: `path('link/', views.link_view, name='link'),` the pattern has no id. Perhaps you meant to use some other view there?

Comment: @Abdul i have a table where uid is pk, and i want to fetch those data, 
Also, instead of ```path('link/', views.link_view, name='link'),```
i can use
```path('link/<int:uid>', views.link_view, name='link_view'),```
where views 
`
def link_view(request, uid):
    results = AffProduct.objects.get(uid=uid)
   return render(request, 'product_view.html', {"results":results})
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you have

```
path('link_view/<int:uid>', views.link_view, name='link_view'),
```

in your URL path

u need have

```
def link_view(request, uid):
    results = AffProduct.objects.get(uid=uid)#Here uid=uid
    return render(request, 'product_view.html', {"results":results})
```

Comment: def link_view(request, uid):
    results = AffProduct.objects.get(uid=uid)
    return render(request, 'product_view.html', {"results":results})